# Открывать разными кнопками одну форму Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

На моей странице есть много кнопок, и форм, которые эти кнопки открывают. По нажатию субмит на форме - кнопка стает неактивной.

```html
<div class="rows">

  <!------------------------1 button------------------------>
  <div class="row">


    <button class="open">btn1</button>
    <form id="myform" onsubmit="return false;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Phone</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
      </div>

      <button class="ave">close</button>
      <button id="submit" class="close">Submit</button>

    </form>


  </div>

  <!---------------------------------------------------->
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function() {
  $('.row').on('click', '.open', function() {
    $(this).parent().children('form').show();
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
  }
  );
  $('.row').on('click',
  '.close',
  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.row').find('.open').html('Куплено!');
    $(this).parent('form').html('Мы вам перезвоним!!!').delay(2000).toggle(500);
  }
  );
  $('.row').on('click',
  '.ave',
  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('form').hide();
    $(this).closest('.row').find('.open').prop('disabled', false);
  }
  );
}
);
```

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы форма была всего одна, а не для каждой кнопки? Такой подход делает код очень длинным. И ко всему формы открываются для каждой кнопки, а мне нужно чтобы только для одной - нажатой в текущий момент. Спасибо за прочтение.

**Правка 1**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как это выглядит. Однотипные кнопки, у каждой своя форма. Нужно сохранить функционал, но так чтобы нельзя было открыть сразу много форм.

Comment: Не совсем понятно. надо чтобы была одна форма и несколько кнопок? Или чтобы одна кнопка и несколько форм? Если можно, сделайте, пожалуйста, пример на jsfiddle.

Comment: Skywave, кнопок много. Форма желательно одна, чтобы не загромождать код. Если возможно так сделать. Главная проблема это то что можно наоткрывать много форм

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ave6uvez/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 вариант. Скрываем все формы перед открытием.

```
$('.row').on('click', '.open', function() {
    $('.row form').hide();
    $(this).parent().children('form').show();
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/skywave/ave6uvez/2/

2 вариант. Сделать одну форму, вынести ее из под .rows и всегда открывать ее.
 Но проблема в том, что для каждой кнопки данные в форме могут отличаться. Тут есть масса решений, зависит от того как отличаются данные.

К примеру, если надо изменить id товара в форме, то можно кнопке добавить атрибут `data-item-id` и в форме после открытия вставлять его в `input`

```
$('form input[name=id]').val(btn.attr('data-item-id'));
```

Либо сделать шаблон формы и через `.replace()` заменять какие то специфичные участки формы.

Comment: Данные в форме всегда одни - 2 поля, по submit вставляется один и тот же текст.  В 1 варианте если открыть три формы, и потом закрыть то кнопки становятся неактивны, все кроме последней открывшей.

Comment: А зачем ее делать неактивной после нажатия?

Answer (score 0):

А если убрать все `<form>` и просто оставить не `submit`, а обычные `button`? При клике на кнопку скрипт jQuery сам может делать "сабмит" данных в диве, где находится эта кнопка.